# How can I access the chrome local storage data in my separate webpage?

Tags: javascript

I tried to use chrome.storage.local.get() to fetch the data but it was giving me an error saying Cannot read property 'local' of undefined.

I am trying to access this in the separate webpage which is not present in the chrome extension.

can any one please help me out over here???

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Rather than targetting a browser specific (and potentially buggy) storage method - why not use the HTML5 localStorage which has good browser support and is easy to implement:

to set:

```
localStorage.setItem("testItem","testValue");
```

to get:

```
var item = localStorage.getItem("testItem"); // gives "testValue"
```

Note that this method only stores strings and there is a session Storage option as well for when you don't want persistence. And it is not inherently secure so don't store sensitive data. But its REALLY useful for storing non-sensitive data and passing variables and values around webpages within your site. You can also use a checking mechanisim like Modernizr if you are worried that you clients may not have local storage (or a browsing in incognito mode) and therefore provide options or an alert for them.